# Read sheet names from a xlsb file

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xlsb

I've been trying to read xlsb files into R.
I've tried using excel.link and readxlsb packages and they do work for reading the file but i also need to read the sheet names.

For a normal xlsx i would go gor GetSheets but it does not work for XLSB.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `readxl` package?

Comment: Try the `readxlsb` package available on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxlsb/vignettes/read-xlsb-workbook.html

Comment: how can i read the sheet names with that?